# Why can't I access the UILabel as a subview of a UIButton

Tags: swift

As the screen shot of the Debug View UIHierarchy indicates every, `UIButton` has a `UILabel` in it.

[image: Screen Shot of Debug View UIHierarchy]

Why, when I work with a `UISearchBar`, am I able to access its subviews and get a reference to the `UITextField` in it by using the `UISearchBar`'s `subviews` property. But for the `UIButton`, its `subviews` property count is zero, indicating that there are no subviews even though the `UILabel` should be a subView.

```
@IBOutlet weak var button: UIButton!
print(button.subviews.count)
```

Comment: You can access button's label like this:
`button.titleLabel`

Comment: thanks for the info but why isn't it in the subViews property of the UIButton

Comment: The subviews of these framework-defined views are an internal implementation detail and not something you should rely on in shipping code.

Comment: @Charles Thanks Charles, are you sating that it should also not be relied on by UISearchBar to access its UITextField subView  `public extension UISearchBar {
    
    public func setTextColor(color: UIColor) {
        let svs = subviews.flatMap { $0.subviews }
        guard let tf = (svs.filter { $0 is UITextField }).first as? UITextField else { return }
        tf.textColor = color
    }
}
`

Comment: If its internal subview structure isn't documented anywhere, there's no guarantee that it won't change in some future release, so I'd be wary about using it. If you get stuck in a situation where there's no better way to do what you need, that's one thing, but this certainly isn't the case for UIButton which has a supported method to access the label view.